# bash syntax error near unexpected token `(' -

Tags: cygwin

Using running cygwin64 terminal, on Windows Server 2012 R2,
I am getting the following error:

```
$ set username=<username>
$ icacls D:\FTPRoot\%username% /inheritance:r /grant HAMFTP02\%username%:(CI)F /t
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Comment: Escape your parenthesis: `\(` and `\)` Also, in questions, please format your text.

Comment: Thank you Ralf   the command now works

"icacls D:\FTPRoot\%username% /inheritance:r /grant "hamnet\domain admins":\(CI\)F"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are entering Windows CMD commands at a bash prompt.

You will need to translate from CMD syntax to bash syntax.

Instead of `set x=y` you need to use `x=y`.

Instead of `%x%` you need to use `$x` or `${x}`.

You will also need to escape bash special characters.

At the bash prompt, you can enter `info bash` to display some terse documentation.

A google search `https://www.google.com/search?q=bash+tutorial` will point you to several gentler introductions to bash.

HTH